# How many terms it takes for the Leibniz series to converge to three decimal places of accuracy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, approximation, pi

I need to find out how many terms it takes for the this series to converge to three decimal places of accuracy of Pi. e.i how many it terms it takes to obtain the value 3.141 from, the series: [Leibniz series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdAAN.png)

I have tried various methods and they haven't seemed to work, but I have seen this formula which does work. However I do not know how to obtain the formula from the original series.

≈
  2
  ⋅
  (
  
    10^k
    
  
  −
  1
  )

I would like to be able show how many terms it takes to get to the three decimal places of accuracy, from the original series. (The Leibniz series)

Comment: Hint: if an alternating series $S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^ia_i$ has strictly decreasing terms ($a_n\gt a_{n+1}$ for all $n$) then $\left|S-\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^ia^i\right|$ is bounded by $a_{n+1}$; can you see why?

Comment: (Also, note that this only gives an upper bound, not a lower one. A lower bound is more complicated to get.)

Comment: so after the upper bound every point converges to amount of decimal places of accuracy?